# Trying to get one record per student to return

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database, inner-join, ms-access-2013

I'm fairly new to databasing in general, and I'm trying to learn.  I understand some of the basics, and mostly use Access internal functions to make things work because it is what I understand.

I am slowly learning SQL, and in trying to read the answers to other's questions, I'm having a lot of trouble extrapolating that to work for my database.

I have a table named "Application Data" or [Application Data] (I have been told that I should not use spaces when writing databases, but it's too much to go back and correct at this point) and I'm trying to get the most recent application to pull up for each student who has one.  I've tried using a LAST on the date field and a Max on the ID field, but both results ultimately produce only one return, whichever one fits out of the whole table, and not whichever is newest per student.

I've tried a few other things, and have been reading for days, but it appears that I need something called an "inner join" to get it to return what I need.  I am not sure exactly what that is or how it works.

Anyway, my query so far in SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Application Data].[Most Recent Application Term]
    ,[Application Data].[Most Recent Application Year]
    ,[Application Data].[Application Date]
    ,[Application Data].[Application Status]
    ,[Application Data].[Application Decision]
    ,[Application Data].Degree
    ,[Application Data].Specialization
FROM [Application Data]
WHERE (
        (
            ([Application Data].ID) = (
                SELECT Max(ID)
                FROM [Application Data]
                )
            )
        )
GROUP BY [Application Data].[Most Recent Application Term]
    ,[Application Data].[Most Recent Application Year]
    ,[Application Data].[Application Date]
    ,[Application Data].[Application Status]
    ,[Application Data].[Application Decision]
    ,[Application Data].Degree
    ,[Application Data].Specialization
    ,[Application Data].PCID
HAVING ((([Application Data].[Application Date]) IS NOT NULL))
ORDER BY [Application Data].PCID DESC
    ,[Application Data].[Application Date] DESC;
```

At this point I'm completely lost, but it's going to feed into another table, from which it will update the main table fields from which all the reports are pulling.

I really appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't know enough to ask the question in a way that fits the requested format.  Perhaps it would be better for me to find a different forum.  I've been trying different code strings copied, pasted, and edited from other solutions.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get any of them work.  Thanks for the heads up, I don't want to frustrate people.

Comment: Your question is quite OK. But the key to get help with SQL is to provide **sample data** and **expected result**: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). -- Reduce to the minimum - the key column(s) and one or two data columns per table are sufficient. Also include the Students table and how it is related to [Application Data].

Answer (score 1):

First some general advices for starters:
Keep your tables clean and normalized and avoid spaces. Each value within one table does specifically relate to the primary key and nothing else.
In your example, the "most recent application" does actually refer to the applicant and not to the application's ID. Thus, move it to another table or just keep it within a query.

My suggestion for your database-design:

1. tbl_Application: App_ID, Student_ID, App_Date, App_Status, App_Decision, App_Specialization, App_Degree
2. tbl_Student: Student_ID, Student_Name etc.

Thus, your application ID contains your desired information and will be linked to the tbl_student via Student_ID. The "Most recent application year" could be added to the tbl_student and might be updated automatically via an UPDATE-query.

Now, let's solve your problem:

First, as mentioned, your query is missing the student information and, thus, the information for which field it should get the maximum values.
Your Inner query will only output a single value - the max ID or Date of all values as it does not include a second field for grouping.
Add the student information to the table and query:

```
SELECT [Application Data].*
FROM [Application Data] INNER JOIN
    (SELECT [Application Data].[Applicant_ID],
            Max([Application Data].[Application Date] As [Most_recent_application],
     FROM [Application Data]
     GROUP BY [Applicant_ID])
    AS qry_application_max
WHERE [Application Date] = [qry_application_max].[Most_recent_application]
```

This should result in a query, showing you the most recent application and all information regarding that particular application stored in the table [Application Data]. You might want to run the inner query (everythin within the parentheses) to see how it works.

This might in general help you understand queries and SQL: Try to build your more complex queries one step after another in the draft view and store them within the database. When everything is done, you can copy the SQL code from the first sub-query to the main-query and try to truncate unnecessary stuff.